# my laravel php desktop application doesn't work after creating installer with inno installer

Tags: laravel, inno-setup, phpdesktop

I have converted this php application into a windows application using php desktop.
I have converted mysql db to sqlite and it works fine.
However, after creating its setup using inno installer, the app returns a blank page and I cannot understand the message returned by the debug console(I have attached a screenshot).

[debug-console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpLPC.png)

Comment: Make sure you have included all binary files provided by phpdesktop (locales/ dir, all the .pak .dll etc files, php/ dir). After installing app with innostup installer check if any of these files are missing in the installation directory.

Comment: I added the files by selecting all and then dragging to  the inno installer setup compiler. Could it be possible any was left out? @CzarekTomczak.

Comment: @GeorgeNjoroge You have to check the actual installation directory in Program Files.

Comment: After compiling with the installer, the folder structure of my project (provided by php desktop) did not remain the same. Thus no folder named php is present. However, all the files in the php folder are available in the installation directory. @MartinPrikryl

Comment: @GeorgeNjoroge The problem is that some files are missing or paths are invalid. You have to figure out which.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have answered my question. The log shows that you are executing `D:\24seven\php\php-cgi.exe`. Does that file exists? If `php-cgi.exe` exists in a different folder, then you are using a wrong path. We cannot help you, unless you show us [mcve].

Comment: @MartinPrikryl He figured it out, he submitted an answer, wrong paths in configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out that I had to change some web_server settings in the **settings.json** file in my installer path so that they look like this

```
 "web_server": {
    "listen_on": ["127.0.0.1", 0],
    "www_directory": "/public",
    "index_files": ["index.html", "index.php"],
    "cgi_interpreter": "/php-cgi.exe",
    "cgi_extensions": ["php"],
    "cgi_temp_dir": "",
    "404_handler": "/public/index.php",
    "hide_files": []
},
```

(remove the www from the paths).
This is because after compiling the project files and folders using inno installer, the `www` folder is no longer there.

Thanks @Czarek and @Martin for answering my question.